# Python package require freeglut as dependency

Tags: python, pip, package, freeglut

I am creating a Python package, and I would like to use freeglut. Is there any way to make it so that when I install the package, it finds a freeglut package for me, and installs it? I know that if I just install PyOpenGL from pip, I can't use freeglut, but if I use a package from [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyopengl](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyopengl), it works. That is only for Windows, though. I also tried to add the link above as a dependency, by uploading it to github then adding pyopengl `@ git+https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rayzchen/PyUnity/master/PyOpenGL-3.1.5-cp38-cp38-win32.whl` as a dependency, but I get an error `TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not NoneType`. I've also tried to use `dependency_links` in setup, but with no luck. This is my setup.py:

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
import os

pyopengl_link = "pyopengl @ git+https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rayzchen/PyUnity/master/PyOpenGL-3.1.5-cp38-cp38-win32.whl"
pyopengl_accelerate_link = "pyopengl-accelerate @ git+https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rayzchen/PyUnity/master/PyOpenGL_accelerate-3.1.5-cp38-cp38-win32.whl"
if os.name == "nt":
    links = [pyopengl_link, pyopengl_accelerate_link]
else:
    links = []

print(links)

with open("README.md", "r") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

setup(
    name = "pyunity",
    version = "0.0.1",
    author = "Ray Chen",
    author_email = "tankimarshal2@gmail.com",
    description = "A Python implementation of the Unity Engine",
    long_description = long_description,
    long_description_content_type = "text/markdown",
    url = "https://github/rayzchen/PyUnity",
    packages = find_packages(),
    classifiers = [
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.7",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: Microsoft :: Windows :: Windows 10",
    ],
    dependency_links = links,
    install_requires = [
        "glfw",
        "pygame",
        *links,
    ],
    python_requires = '>=3.7',
)
```

This was just for fun, so please don't criticise me for trying to implement Unity in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way that I found was to put `pyopengl @ https://github.com/rayzchen/pyunity/blob/master/PyOpenGL-3.1.5-cp38-cp38-win32.whl` as a solution, not `pyopengl @ git+https://github.com/rayzchen/pyunity/blob/master/PyOpenGL-3.1.5-cp38-cp38-win32.whl`. I think the `git+` would clone the repo, then build the package.